# Compiling Karelia's ConnectionKit in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, cocoa, webdav

I am trying to build and use the ConnectionKit framework in my code, but compiling it is yielding close to 100 errors, and about as many 'deprecated' warnings.  Does anyone still use this framework, or is it too out of date?  When I load it into XCode, I have to change it's default SDK from 10.4 to 10.7, could this be the source of my problems?  And if so, is there a way to get the 10.4 SDK into Xcode 4? All I want to do is incorporate webdav support into my app. Perhaps a precompiled framework would be easier to work with...

Comment: Where did you download the source from?

Comment: https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit.git